# Adding an image (icon/symbol) into the font

Tags: database, image, fonts, icons

Is there any way I can add images to the font I'm using?

I've been working on my card game (see link in my profile) and the symbols I use are a part of the language of the game. I want to be able to freely use my icons/symbols in my text to any program I use. Ultimately, I need to create a database and would need to put the text (that includes the icons/symbols) in an area of an app or website.

For the past 4 years, I've gotten away with manually inserting the symbols as pictures and shrinking them, but it's too inflexible for my plans.

The icons/symbols are full color vector images created in either Illustrator or Fireworks CS5 (my wife made them). The color is important as part of the symbol.

Thank you! hewhocomes

Answer (score 0):

You should try font awesome: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/
It is a library of icons easy to use and install and you can change the color of the icons or any other attribute just as you would regular text using: color: #some-color.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for sharing Font Awesome with me. It looks great, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to put full color images into an existing font. I'm making a database that will take text that includes my images in it and show it on my app/database when a person clicks to display the desired information.